# How to mongoose aggregate find data from a filed of array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array like this on DB.

```
 [{
    _id: 61c9b7ac365cae3e9e406d8d,
    user: 61c879d080d04078d7342b34,
    cart: 
     [
      _id:"61c85d2c7ab0861b703da7d3"
      title:"some title"
      price:100
      description:"some des",
      user: {_id:"61c7f81469176d17a540712e" }
     ]
    }]
```

I used:

```
   const { sellerId } = req.params;
          const order = await Orders.find({ "user": { "$in": sellerId } })
          .sort("-created") // or .sort({ field: 'asc', created: -1 });
```

I want all the data of cart items user field _id..

Answer (score 0):

> I have an array like this on DB.

Do you mean u have a mongoDB collection named Orders with the above data?

> I want all the data of cart items user field _id..

Find will return the cursor to the matching records. Try

```
await Orders.find({ "user": { "$in": sellerId } })
          .sort("-created").forEach(function(err, order) {
  console.log(order.cart)
});
```